# Requisição enviada mais de uma vez ao selecionar um campo do form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Quando eu seleciono algum campo especifico de um formulário, disparo uma requisição para carregar algumas informações essenciais para conclusão do preenchimento do mesmo, só que ao selecionar um campo do formulário ele dispara 3, 4 requisições e isso faz com o que meus dados de um option por exemplo fiquem duplicados dentro do form.

```
// requisição
$('body').on('click', '#cmbContrato', function () {

    contrato = $("#cmbContrato").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'ProtocoloExterno/GetItensContrato',
        data: { dado: contrato },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (dados) {
            if (dados !== 0) {

                   var selectbox = $('#cmbItensContrato');

                    $.each(dados, function (i, d) {
                        $('<option>').val(d.id).text(d.value).appendTo(selectbox);
                    });
                }
            } 
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Erro ao enviar AJAX");
        }
    });

});


// metodo em c# asp.net mvc



[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public JsonResult GetItensContrato()
{
    List<object> resultado = new List<object>();
    long numeroContrato = 0;
    if (Request.QueryString["dado"] != "")
    {
         numeroContrato = long.Parse(Request.QueryString["dado"]);
    }

    var infosContrato = db.ItemContrato.Where(c => c.ContratoId == numeroContrato.ToString()).Select(c => c.ItemRCid);

    foreach(int itensContrato in infosContrato)
    {
         resultado.Add(new { id = itensContrato, value = itensContrato });
    }
        return Json(resultado, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

Como solucionar esse problema?

Comment: conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Consegui resolver sim, mas era a chamada externa... mas continua vindo dado replicados @LeandroAngelo

Comment: No json eles vem duplicados? ou apenas estão adicionando aos que já estão na tela? você adicionou o `remove()` da minha resposta editada?

Comment: no Json eles vem duplicados, o erro está no retorno do entity

Comment: Você diz duplicado, porque está passando o mesmo valor para o `id` e o `value`? Nesse trecho: `resultado.Add(new { id = itensContrato, value = itensContrato });`

Comment: Não, que o retorno que vem do Entity manda duas vezes o mesmo registro

Comment: Você já fez a mesma consulta no banco? Será que você não tem de fato registros duplicados lá?

Comment: Não tem mano, já fiz sim, é pau do retorno do json do entity

Answer (score 1):

Você está fazendo o bind no evento errado, da forma como você definiu, toda vez que o usuário clicar no `#cmbContrato` você dispara a requisição ajax.

E como observado pelo @Barbetta, você está sempre somando elementos em seu `#cmdItensContrato`. Então no seu caso além do evento errado você está interpretando equivocadamente o resultado obtido e atribuindo a causa como unicamente relacionada aos multiplos disparos da requisição ajax.

Mude para o `change`

```js
$('body').on('change', '#cmbContrato', function() {
  var contrato = $("#cmbContrato").val();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'ProtocoloExterno/GetItensContrato',
    data: {
      dado: contrato
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(dados) {
      if (dados !== 0) {

        var selectbox = $('#cmbItensContrato');
         
        //Removendo os itens presentes no segundo combobox;
        selectbox.find('option').remove();        

        $.each(dados, function(i, d) {
          $('<option>').val(d.id).text(d.value).appendTo(selectbox);
        });
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("Erro ao enviar AJAX");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <select id="cmbContrato">
      <option value="1">Contrato 1</option>
      <option value="2">Contrato 2</option>
      <option value="3">Contrato 3</option>
      <option value="4">Contrato 4</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: mesmo assim ele continua enviar a requisição duas vezes

Comment: não tenho, id é unico e blá blá

Comment: Se ainda ainda assim ele está disparando duas vezes, é porque você está fazendo o bind mais de uma vez. Procure em seu código para ver se não tem outra declaração de `$('body').on('change', '#cmbContrato'`

Comment: Não, acontece que todos os binds estão sendo disparados mais de uma vez e está sendo chamado apenas uma vez

Comment: O seu js está escrito diretamente na página ou view ou sendo incluído como um arquivo exeterno? Verifique se você não está importanto ele na master e na view ou declarando ele no bundle e importando novamente depois. E de qualquer forma, você precisa trocar o `click` por `change` isso já vai fazer com que o ajax dispare duas vezes.

Comment: Não sei se pode ser isso.. caso esteja errado removo o comentário.. mas não vi no código dele, ele limpando o `select ` antes de preenche-lo de novo com os dados vindos do servidor. talvez seja isso

Comment: @LeandroAngelo isso que pensei, estou chamando ele em um modal, cujo no modal e na pagina que chama o modal estou chamando o mesmo arquivo..

Comment: E veja o comentário do @Barbetta, você não está limpando o `#cmbItensContrato` antes de adicionar os novos itens, eles vão acabar empilhando.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, mesmo só vindo uma requisição, ele meio que duplica os dados... não sei se é o retorno do Json que está errado

Comment: @gabrielfalieri, veja minha última edição à resposta.